# Using PDO to UPDATE a value based on its old value within the database

Tags: php, sql, pdo, sql-update

So say I have a query like this:

```
$columnstr = "sum";
$valsstr = "sum + 5";

$query = "UPDATE mytable SET $columnstr = ?";
$updatenum = $db->prepare($query);
$updatenum->bindParam(1, $valsstr);
$updatenum->execute();
```

The problem is I don't think this will work and I can't exactly test it for various reasons. Sum is an integer column but I'm binding a string to it, hoping it will know to add 5 to "sum".

Also it needs to be sent in like this as it won't always be based off a columns current value.

The query I want to have sent in this case is:

```
"UPDATE mytable SET sum=sum+5"
```

Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You answered your own question with your last query example

Comment: I had stated the question really badly, can you re-read and see if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use query parameters for expressions.  A parameter takes the place only of a single scalar value.  So it's not that PDO can't bind string variables, it's that your string "sum+5" will be evaluated as an integer, not as an SQL expression.  MySQL's idea of the integer value of "sum+5" is 0.

This is not a limitation of PDO, it's how SQL is defined.  It would work the same way regardless of client programming language or brand of RDBMS.  This is common hurdle for developers learning SQL.  *Parameters are not string interpolation.*  String interpolation happens before the SQL is parsed during `prepare()`.  Parameters are sent after the SQL is parsed, during `execute()`.  The parameter value cannot force the SQL to be re-parsed, and therefore it can't introduce extra expression syntax to the query.  This is how it protects against SQL injection.

If you have input strings that *might* be expressions sometimes and other times are constant values, you have a complex case.  The best you can do is to write code to test your input string and do either string interpolation or parameterization.

You can pass an object to a database query method instead of a string (PHP being a loosely typed language makes this easy).  If the value is an object, then interpolate it into the query string.  If the method argument is a scalar, then use a parameter.

```
function my_update_method($args) {
  $params = array();
  $query = "UPDATE mytable SET ";
  foreach ($args as $column => $value) {
    if ($value instanceof SQLTerm)
    {
      $query .= "`" . $column . "` = " . $value; /* calls object's __toString() method */
    } else {
      $query .= "`" . $column . "` = ?";
      $params[] = $value;
    }
  }

  $updatenum = $db->prepare($query);
  $updatenum->execute($params);
}
```

The SQLTerm class is just a wrapper for a string, its only purpose is to be an object instead of a string, so we can tell when a value is a string scalar to be parameterized, versus an expression that can't be parameterized.

```
class SQLTerm
{
  protected $string;
  public function __construct($string) {
    $this->string = $string;
  }
  public function __toString() {
    return $this->string;
  }
}
```

This means the caller is responsible for creating a SQLTerm objects in a way that avoids SQL injection risks.

Comment: Thank you a lot for taking such time and going into such depth to explain why it wouldn't work. I marked your answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. To the best of my knowledge, only columns where you directly specify the value will be able to be parameterized.

The following is valid SQL.

```
UPDATE mytable SET col1=col1+5, col2=?, col3=? WHERE mykey=?
```

I just tested it out in IBM DB2 9.7, but it's been valid syntax for years.

Comment: I realised I had asked the wrong question, being silly. I editted and I hope it makes more sense or the question is more obvious.

Comment: It is more a question about how pdo works. Binding a string value to an integer column

Comment: Ok, what you're trying to do is pass an expression `sum+5` as a parameter, which will not work.